# rsync: @ERROR: auth failed on module tomcat_backup

Tags: redhat, rsync

I just can't figure out what's going on with my RSync.  I'm running RSync on RHEL5, ip = xx.xx.xx.97.  It's getting files from RHEL5, ip = xx.xx.xx.96.

Here's what the log (which I specified on the RSync command line) shows on xx.97 (the one requesting the files):

```
(local time)
2015/08/30 13:40:01 [17353] @ERROR: auth failed on module tomcat_backup
2015/08/30 13:40:01 [17353] rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1530) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Here's what the log(which is specified in the rsyncd.conf file) shows on xx.96 (the one supplying the files):

```
(UTC time)
2015/08/30 07:40:01 [8836] name lookup failed for xx.xx.xx.97: Name or service not known
2015/08/30 07:40:01 [8836] connect from UNKNOWN (xx.xx.xx.97)
2015/08/30 07:40:01 [8836] auth failed on module tomcat_backup from unknown (xx.xx.xx.97): password mismatch
```

Here's the actual rsync.sh command called from xx.xx.xx.97 (the requester):

```
export RSYNC_PASSWORD=rsyncclient
rsync -havz --log-file=/usr/local/bin/RSync/test.log rsync://rsyncclient@xx.xx.xx.96/tomcat_backup/ProcessSniffer/ /usr/local/bin/ProcessSniffer
```

Here's the rsyncd.conf on xx.xx.xx.97:

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
[files]
    name = tomcat_backup
    path = /usr/local/bin/
    comment = The copy/backup of tomcat from .96
    uid = tomcat
    gid = tomcat
    read only = no
    list = yes
    auth users = rsyncclient
    secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
    hosts allow = xx.xx.xx.96/255.255.255.0
```

Here's the rsyncd.secrets on xx.xx.xx.97:

```
files:files
```

Here's the rsyncd.conf on xx.xx.xx.96 (the supplier of files):

Note: there is a 'cwrsync' (Windows version of rsync) *successfully* calling for files also (xx.xx.xx.100)

Note: yes, there is the possibility of xx.96 requesting files from xx.97. However, this is NOT actually happening.

It's commented out of the init.d mechanism.

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
pid file = /var/run/rsync.pid
strict modes = false
[files]
        name = tomcat_backup
        path = /usr/local/bin
        comment = The copy/backup of tomcat from xx.97
        uid = tomcat
        gid = tomcat
        read only = no
        list = yes
        auth users = rsyncclient
        secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
        hosts allow = xx.xx.xx.97/255.255.255.0, xx.xx.xx.100/255.255.255.0
```

Here's the rsyncd.secrets on xx.xx.xx.97:

```
files:files
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something else.  I had a script calling the rsync command, and that was causing the problem.  The actual rsync command line was ok.
Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been through when I got this error. My first thinking was to check rsync server log. and it is not in the place configured in `rsync.conf`. Then I checked the log printed in `systemctl status rsyncd`

```
rsyncd[23391]: auth failed on module signaling from unknown (172.28.15.10): missing secret for user "rsync_backup"
rsyncd[23394]: Badly formed boolean in configuration file: "no # rsync daemon before transmission, change to the root directory and limited within.".
rsyncd[23394]: params.c:Parameter() - Ignoring badly formed line in configuration file: ignore errors # ignore some io error informations.
rsyncd[23394]: Badly formed boolean in configuration file: "false  # if true, cannot upload file to this server.".
rsyncd[23394]: Badly formed boolean in configuration file: "false # if true, cannot download file from this server.".
rsyncd[23394]: Badly formed boolean in configuration file: "false       # if true, can only list files here.".
```

Combining the fact that log configuration does not come into play. It seems that the comment after each line of configuration in rsync.conf makes configurations invalid. So I deleted those `# ...` and restart rsyncd.